# split strings with multiple special characters into lists without importing anything in python

Tags: python, split, python-3.6

i need to make a program that will capitalize the first word in a sentence and i want to be sure that all the special characters that are used to end a sentence can be used.

i can not import anything! this is for a class and i just want some examples to do this.

i have tried to use if to look in the list to see if it finds the matching character and do the correct split operatrion...

this is the function i have now... i know its not good at all as it just returns the original string...

```
def getSplit(userString):
    userStringList = []
    if "? " in userString:
        userStringList=userString.split("? ")
    elif "! " in userStringList:
        userStringList = userString.split("! ")
    elif ". " in userStringList:
        userStringList = userString.split(". ")
    else:
        userStringList = userString
    return userStringList
```

i want to be able to input something like `this is a test. this is a test? this is definitely a test!`

and get `[this is a test.', 'this is a test?', 'this is definitely a test!']`

and the this is going to send the list of sentences to another function to make the the first letter capitalized for each sentence.

this is an old homework assignment that i could only make it use one special character to separate the string into a list. buti want to user to be able to put in more then just one kind of sentence...

Comment: that's bad to return a list or a string depending on the outcome of the tests... please provide input & expected output.

Comment: Can you import things from the python standard library? Like `re`?

Answer (score 0):

I would split the string at each white space. Then scan the list for words that contain the special character. If any is present, the next word is capitalised. Join the list back at the end. Of course, this assumes that there are no more than two consecutive spaces between words.

```
def capitalise(text):
        words = text.split()

        new_words = [words[0].capitalize()]
        i = 1
        while i < len(words) - 1:
                new_words.append(words[i])
                if "." in words[i] or "!" in words[i] or "?" in words[i]:
                        i += 1
                        new_words.append(words[i].capitalize())
                i += 1

        return " ".join(new_words)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may hep. use `str.replace` to replace special chars with space and the use `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
def getSplit(userString):
    return userString.replace("!", " ").replace("?", " ").replace(".", " ").split()

print(map(lambda x:x.capitalize, getSplit("sdfsdf! sdfsdfdf? sdfsfdsf.sdfsdfsd!fdfgdfg?dsfdsfgf")))
```

Comment: `lambda x:x.capitalize()` => `str.capitalize`

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you could use re.split(), but since you cannot import anything, the best option would be just to do a for loop. Here it is:

```
def getSplit(user_input):
    n = len(user_input)
    sentences =[]
    previdx = 0
    for i in range(n - 1):
        if(user_input[i:i+2] in ['. ', '! ', '? ']):
            sentences.append(user_input[previdx:i+2].capitalize())
            previdx = i + 2
    sentences.append(user_input[previdx:n].capitalize())
    return "".join(sentences)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the re module which is available by default in python, this is how you could do it:

```
import re
a = 'test this. and that, and maybe something else?even without space.   or with multiple.\nor line breaks.'
print(re.sub(r'[.!?]\s*\w', lambda x: x.group(0).upper(), a))
```

Would lead to:

```
test this. And that, and maybe something else?Even without space.   Or with multiple.\nOr line breaks.
```